# How do I install and mount an exFAT partition?

Tags: filesystem, exfat

I have searched around here and with Google, and none of the instructions I have found work with Oneric.

How do install exFAT and mount an exFAT partition in the latest release of Kubuntu?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You will need the packages [`exfat-fuse`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/otherosfs/exfat-fuse) and [`exfat-utils`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/otherosfs/exfat-utils) to allow you to read and write on exFAT drives:

[For 14.04 and higher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14838/is-there-a-simple-way-to-add-exfat-support):

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Afterwards you just need to plug in the HDD and you're good to go.

Comment: Update, this works on 12.10

Comment: I required sudo apt-get install fuse-exfat exfat-utils

Comment: on 13.10: sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse

Comment: On 12.10, after adding the `relan/exfat` repository and updating, I had to **only** install `fuse-exfat` (this will automatically select `fuse-utils` as dependency). If you install `exfat-utils` it automatically installs `exfat-fuse`, which then prevents the installation of `fuse-exfat` (due to potential overwrite conflict).

Comment: Also to note that when I tried to install `fuse-exfat` without adding the repository, it was not found. Therefore "For 12.10, you can install these packages by using third command **without any other process**" was not true for me.

Comment: works for 14.04

Answer (score 22):

### 13.10 and later

You will need the `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` packages.  Install them with:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Your exFAT formatted drives should now (auto) mount fine.

Comment: for me installing exfat-fuse seemed to be all that was needed? Anyway thanks for the tip (basically, in 13.10, you no longer need the extra ppa stuff, just install this instead [if it doesn't work you may need to enable the universe repository and apt-get update])

Comment: exfat-fuse will download exfat-utils as dependency. <br/>
If you just write `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse` it will download both the packages.