# Mount exFAT partition in virtual guest machine

Tags: virtualbox, exfat

I have a real Ubuntu 12.10 installation being virtualized under a Windows 8 host, by using the `VBoxManage.exe internalcommands createrawvmdk` method.

I'm trying to mount an exFAT partition into the virtualized machine (which is the partition of shared work files), but even though I have fuse-exfat installed, and the partition is perfectly mountable while booting entirely into Ubuntu, I can't mount it while virtualizing it.

1- If I make a full vmdk image of the HDD, including all partitions, Ubuntu 12.10 "sees" the partition, and trying to mount it throws this error:

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyUSn.png

2- If I make a machine with only the linux partitions, + the exFAT partition. Again Ubuntu "sees" the partition and the result is:

```
Error: fsync failed
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4SkC.png

3- If I make a machine with only the linux partitions, and try to mount it, Ubuntu doesn't "see" the partition, and I get this error:

Image: i.stack.imgur.com/q1hz5.png

I've tried using the VirtualBox' "Shared Folders" functionality but even though I install the "Guest Additions", the system doesn't seem to recognize the shared folder:

Image: i.stack.imgur.com/yLU0E.png

Help?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the OS of the guest?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100278/how-do-i-install-and-mount-an-exfat-partition. What do you get on `mount -t exfat`(do **not** capitalize FAT)?

Comment: The linux install being virtualized is Ubuntu 12.10. Using exfat not capitalized works but still throws an error. Updated the question.