# Mounting of external Harddrive

Tags: mount

Im using Ubuntu v12.04.Its working fine but Im not able to mount my external harddrive.It says there is an error in mounting the hdd because of unknown file system exfat. Hope to find a few solutions.

Comment: This might be a dublicate of this http://askubuntu.com/questions/100278/how-do-i-install-and-mount-an-exfat-partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did You try this:

```
   apt-add-repository ppa:relan/exfat
   apt-get install fuse-exfat
```

?

more: http://apcmag.com/how-to-enable-exfat-in-ubuntu.htm

Comment: Please explain what these commands are doing.

Comment: Im very sorry for this........The hdd has a problem with the usb wire...Doesn get detected on all systems....Thanks a lot for your help anyways