# Can't mount SDXC card on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: partitioning, mount, sd-card, camera

I've tried the solution from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315094/cant-mount-64-gb-sdxc), but even with `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` installed, I can't mount my SDXC card (formatted in my Canon T3i camera).

`ls -l /dev/sd*` reports:

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  0 Dec 29 17:10 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  1 Dec 29 16:14 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  2 Dec 29 16:42 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  5 Dec 29 16:14 /dev/sda5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Dec 29 17:16 /dev/sdb
```

I do note that I'm not seeing `/dev/sdb1`.

`fdisk -l /dev/sdb` reports:

```
You must set cylinders.
You can do this from the extra functions menu.

Disk /dev/sdb: 0 MB, 65536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 0 cylinders, total 128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1           32768   125171711    62569472    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Again, I note a couple things: I'm told I need to **set cylinders**, which I'm not sure how to do; and I see that the partition starts at `32768` instead of `0` or thereabouts.

The card mounts fine on my Windows 7 system, and in my camera. I tried formatting it `NTFS` on my Windows box but my camera rejected it, so I did a low-level format with the camera to get things back to square one.

Comment: Not sure if this works on linux too, but `diskutil list` shows all of your disks. Maybe you did not mount it

Comment: I *can't* mount it. Ubuntu doesn't see it as a proper partition, for whatever reason.

Comment: might want to go [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/469030/seems-ubuntu-cannot-read-sd-cards)

Comment: I searched through Ask Ubuntu before I asked the question. Most of the solutions seemed to be "install `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` and you're good to go. That's not the situation in which I find myself, unfortunately.

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone else: My problem was that the SD-to-USB card reader I was using was incompatible with my SDXC card. A new card reader that supports SDXC was the solution.